# What would be the "best" way to design a buck/boost circuit to convert 9Vdc to 10V and 5V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, buck-boost

I have an old console that I'd like to convert to USB-C that requires both 10V 1A and 5V 2A. Ideally, I'd like to run it off a 9V 2.2A source, so that it can be powered with a commonly available 20W USB-C charger. This isn't 100% necessary but would be nice to have.

From what I've looked into so far, it seems the only option would be to use a **boost converter** for the 10V 1A and a **buck converter** for the 5V 2A. A quick calculation would seem to indicate that this would require around 75% efficiency to work with a 9V 2.2A source, does this seem feasible?

Also, on a more niche point, does anyone know of a suitable dual-output buck-boost converter that would be suitable, rather than having separate ones for each function? The only ones I've managed to find seem to be a little too complex and/or expensive.

Comment: Yes, separate buck and boost converters. 10V isn't a common output voltage - you'll want to use an adjustable converter and adjust it to 10V. You might consider testing whether the console will work okay with the 10V input being 9V. If it does work it'll save you a converter. *Flashback to ["Can you run a NES from AA batteries?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTqcb8hl8YI)*

Comment: (and [the same for Sega Genesis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5UltdmlnL0))

Comment: I'll check the schematic for the power management side of things inside the console, but from what I've read, it seems the console (a Neo Geo CD) is pretty fussy about the exact voltages required.

Comment: Just to be clear: a buck/boost converter can start with a voltage that's either higher or lower than the required output. But it still only produces one output voltage. To get two output voltages, you need two converters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I have an old console that I'd like to convert to USB-C that requires
> both 10V 1A and 5V 2A.*

That's 20 watts in total.

> *Ideally I'd like to run it off a 9V 2.2A source*

That's 19.8 watts so no, this won't work.

You will likely need something like a 22 watt supply or greater.

> *does anyone know of a suitable dual-output buck-boost converter that
> would be suitable, rather than having separate ones for each function?*

Requests for product recommendations are off-topic but, I would say to stick with separate regulators if you can find a way of supplying maybe 22 watts or above.

Comment: Ha, yes, I'd messed up a pretty straightforward calculation! Those 10V and 5V requirements are what the old power supply provides, I haven't actually measured what the console draws, so I might do that given that the price jumps up quite a bit for chargers over 20W. Obviously it'll vary from device to device, but would you say as a rule of thumb that 90% efficiency would be what I could expect from a buck/boost converter?

Comment: There are buck convertors and there are boost converters. There are also buck-boost converters but, what you want is not what is called a buck-boost controller. What you require is a buck converter and a boost converter. I just want to get terminology right. You might get 95% efficiency from a good buck converter and, you might get 85% efficiency from a reasonable boost converter. Measure your load and decide how much spare room you have is my advice @Marmotta

Comment: @Marmotta if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, I'd like to run it off a 9V 2.2A source, so that it can be powered with a commonly available 20W USB-C charger.

From a search, to get more than 15W from a USB-C charger the *Power Sink* needs to implement the *USB Power Delivery Specification* (USB PD) to request a supply voltage of more than 5V and/or a current of more than 3A.

The abstract of the Texas Instruments [USB PD Power Negotiations Application Report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva842/slva842.pdf) contains:

> USB PD is required in USB Type-C systems for power levels above 15 W (5 V at 3 A) up to 100 W (20 V at 5 A) according to the specification.

The answer [USB-C power negotiation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/611877/101063) has some more information, and includes a link to the USB C specification.

To avoid the complication of USB PD, perhaps you could use something like a 12V 2A supply instead of a USB-C charger.